# Homomorphism rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

$Hom(R,S)$denote the set of all homomorphisms of rings.    $Char$ denote characteristic of a ring.
1) If either $Char R \neq 0$ but $Char S=0$ then $Hom(R,S)=\{0\}$
 For example $Hom(\mathbb{Z}_{n},\mathbb{Z})=\{0\}$
2) If $Char R \neq 0$ and $Char S \neq 0$ but $Char S$ does not divide $Char R$
For example $Hom(\mathbb{Z}_{n},\mathbb{Z}_{m})={0}$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $gcd(m,n)=1$    Upto this i am getting all things.  Now to prove the following i need help.  In which i again clear notations as follow   $\mathbb{Z}[x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}]$ denote ring of several variables.  Show that $Hom(\mathbb{Z}[x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}],S)=S^{n}$ for any ring $S$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
I try it. But not getting any ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the universal property of the polynomial ring gives you that you have to specify an element of $S$ for every element $x_i$ to obtain a unique ring homomorphism. Vice versa every ring homomorphism gives such elements. So ring homomorphisms correspond 1-1 to $n$-tuples in $S$, i.e. $Hom(\mathbb Z[x_1,\cdots,x_n],S]=S^n$

Comment: Pls explain it in detail.

Comment: @user197636 or perhaps you can try to think about what he said and be more specific in your question. What exactly do you not understand? What exactly about Dan's answer confused you? ...etc

Comment: Ya. I try it from last 15 Days. So confuse alot.

Comment: Whether we have to define map

Comment: $\phi$:\mathbb{Z}[x_{1}.,x_{n}] to S

Comment: The map would be as canonical as in my answer: $Hom(\mathbb Z[x_1,\cdots,x_n],S) \ni \phi \mapsto (\phi(x_1),\cdots,\phi(x_n))\in S^n$

Answer (score 0):

$\phi:\mathbb{Z}[ x_{1},\ldots,x_{n }]\rightarrow S^{n}$ defined by
$\phi(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})=(x_{1}+x_{2}+…+x_{n})$ for each $x_{i}\in S$

Comment: @Dan thanks alot